# Syncing the data in arrays between activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am making a food order app. There is a full page `ListView` on my main page called `MenuActivity` and there is a `Button` when I press it, it will intent to the `CartActivity` page.

I have arrays `food` for food name, `imgID` for food images, `butPlus` `butMinus` to adjust the amount of food and `amount` to keep the amount of each food with an initial value of 0.

I have a method called `addAmount` , `minusAmount` in `MenuAcitivity` that will increase, decrease the amount. It is called by an `Adapter` of this class.

```
public static void addAmount(int position) {
    amount[position] += 1;
}
```

Going to `CartActivity`, I used this to pass all my values.

```
public void goToCart(MenuItem menuItem) {
    Intent in = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, CartActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("list", amount);
    in.putExtra("imgID", imgID);
    in.putExtra("nameList", food);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

to receive the values I created new `ArrayList` in `CartActivity` to get the data of the food that the amount in not zero.

```
        // add components to array lists
        // addList, removeList are methods to add,remove in my new ArrayList created in this class
    for (int i = 0; i < amountList.length; i++) {
        if (amountList[i] != 0) {
            if (!foodListFinal.contains(foodList[i]))
                addList(amountList[i], foodList[i], imgID[i]);
        } else if (amountList[i] == 0 && !foodListFinal.isEmpty()) {
            if (foodListFinal.contains(foodList[i])) {
                index = foodListFinal.indexOf(foodList[i]);
                removeList(amountList[index], foodList[index], imgID[index]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I have a method called `addAmount` , `minusAmount` in `CartAcitivity` that will increase, decrease the amount just like in the `MenuActivity`. It is called by an Adapter of this class which is not the same one with `MenuActivity`.

```
public static void addAmount(int position) {
    int newAmount = (amountListFinal.get(position)) + 1;
    amountListFinal.set(position, newAmount);
}

public static void minusAmount(int position) {
    int newAmount = (amountListFinal.get(position)) - 1;
    amountListFinal.set(position, newAmount);
}
```

Here is my problem..

When I decrease `amount` in the `CartActivity` to 0 and I went back to `MenuActivity` it correctly says 0, but if I switch to `CartActivity` again the app crashes with an error saying index out of bound.

Please help me with this, or is there any better way to do this please enlighten me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

for which array caused this error : " saying index out of bound." , foodList or amountList array ? It's gonna help you

Comment: Thanks for answering!! I got it worked out now :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use secondary storage to store your changes. Also passing whole array to another activity is not recommended.Use any database to insert change in it and then in cart activity retrieve all data.
This way ,you can achieve same state of amount in various objects.

Comment: Thank you!! I think I'm getting it to work using SQLite :D